# Errors when I create a class in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code:

```
class SignInActivity {
    private lateinit var binding: SingInBinding
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = SingInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    } // Start GameActivity
}
```

But I have errors in `onCreate`, `layoutInflater`, and `setContentView`: unresolved reference.

How can I fix it?

I want to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not extending any Activity class, you should do something like

```
class SignInActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   ...
}
```